# Alternative to ng-repeat if I don't need scope

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a situation where I am generating a LOT of rows and columns using Angular and the performance is terrible!!

I'm assuming that it's because my ng-repeat is creating a new scope for each of the elements that it creates, however, this particular function doesn't need to watch anything.  I'm simply using ng-repeat as a loop to generate HTML that will never change.

Is there another angular method that I can use to loop through model data and generate HTML without using ng-repeat that will improve performance?

Comment: Maybe some of these solutions will be helpful: http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/

Comment: if your html is simple, you can try mine http://plnkr.co/edit/1JIQPY8zK4CEwB9gNjfK - [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/dot-dota-handlebar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `directive` which will accept the `ng-repeat` values and then do whatever you want to do in that directive e.g. create a table which will have those values.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need the scope to access the data for the current iterations item.

However, as your data never changes, you might get take a look at [`bindonce`](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) or the  [`slyRepeat`](https://github.com/scalyr/angular) directive.